# Why isn't the mysql trigger working?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables; receivables and chargesLedger. When a new charge is inserted into the chargesLedger table, I need the subtotal for the corresponding receivable to update. I thought I could accomplish this by adding the new chargeAmt value from the charges record to the subtotal of the receivable so I tried by creating the following trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `bfs`.`chargesLedger_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `chargesLedger` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 update `receiveables`
 SET subtotal = subtotal + new.chargeAmt
 WHERE invoiceID = new.invoiceID; 
END
```

The charges record references the receivables Primary Key invoiceID. It however is not updating the receivables record. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there an error message?.

Comment: All other things being equal the trigger works fine. I would check that subtotal does not default to null (null + 10 = null) and would test for null. Also the query assumes that there is a match found in receivables on invoiceid. Personally I would code for a not found.